# Forge Viewer material manager getModelMaterials() doesn't return added materials

Tags: autodesk-viewer

When I add a new material using `materialManager.addMaterial(...)` and afterwards, call `materialManager.getMaterials()`, the returned map doesn't include my added material. If I want to reuse my material, I have to get it from `materialManager._materials`. Is there a reason `materialManager.getMaterials()` doesn't return user added materials?

Answer (score 0):

`getModelMaterials()` and `findMaterial()` will find materials with a specific name prefix `model:x|mat` only. The `x` stands for `Model.id`.

So, I would advise you to add material in this way, then call

```js
const model = viewer.model;
cosnt materialManager = viewer.mpl.matman();
const materialNameHash = materialManager._getMaterialHash(model, 'my-red-mat'); //!<<< `model:1|mat:my-red-mat`

const mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: new THREE.Color('red'),  side: THREE.DoubleSide });

materialManager.addMaterial( materialNameHash, mat, true );

// find my-red-mat
materialManager.findMaterial(model, 'my-red-mat');
```